# Flash Notices and Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have code thats working like it should but I have no idea why it's working...

I posted the code here and don't understand why during the update the new data for @person is available if only query is made to the DB so how can the flash notice get the new values?

http://pastebin.com/gDEDuW7c

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

When you call @person.update_attributes(params[:person]) your actually updating the @person object which is why you get the new name thereafter.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Gyln, Thanks for the reply! So the update_attributes method on the object always updates the main object... Do you know where I can find some more info on this? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You can check out the Rails API Docs here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html . If your new to rails check out RailsCasts.com.